# Manually adding a Null value to a string field in an attribute table in ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, attribute-table, editing, arcgis-10.4, null

When I'm in an editing session and I manually delete a value from a numeric field the value turns to null (`<Null>`). Manually deleting a value in a string field creates an empty string, not a `Null`. Currently I select the record and field calculate `Null`, which is clunkier. Is there a fast way to change a string to a `Null` in an attribute table?

Comment: I _think_ that in the attribute table, if you remove text from a String field, and type <Null> it will actually set the field to `NULL`.  I will check this and post an answer if confirmed

Comment: @Midavalo I can confirm that this method adds the string `<Null>` and not a null value.

Comment: I've just confirmed my suspicion is correct (although not through the attribute table) - see my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This solution works using the Attribute Editor, but does **not** work through the Attribute Table.

Select the records you want to update to `NULL`

Open the Attribute Editor from the Editor toolbar

[image]

If you have more than one feature you want to update, select the top row (this makes any attributes you edit update all selected records)

[image]

In the field you want to update, type `<Null>`

[image]

This will actually set the field to `NULL` for the selected records, and not to the string value `"<Null">`.  You can confirm this by doing a Select by Attributes `textfield is NULL` - if they are true `NULL` they'll be selected.

[image]

Comment: I like this approach as well if you're manually editing lots of rows and cannot automate the process any further. +1

Comment: Confirmed that this works in ArcGIS Pro as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could replace any empty strings with another string from the field calculator. 
Using python, where STATE_NAME is the field:

```
!STATE_NAME!.replace("", "thisisareplacement")
```

If you mean `Null` not as a string you could try using a codeblock:

```
def replace(x):
  if x =="":
    return None
  else:
    return x
```

Under field, `replace(!STATE_NAME!)`

Beyond that you could use if / else statements in your workflow to further automate the process based on your specifications.

You may also be able to do this by setting defaults, but you need to have the data in a geodatabase where `NULL` values are allowed see here: https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000012852

Comment: In Python, the term for `NULL` is `None`.  Adding `"Null"` is adding the text "Null", not setting the contents to `NULL`.  Perhaps `!STATE_NAME!.replace("", None)` might work better?

Comment: @Midavalo realized that and edited

Comment: great - I think my suggested `!STATE_NAME!.replace("", None)` won't work either, as you need a string value for replace.  Returning None is a better option.  +1

Comment: This is all more complicated than my current method of selecting the row manually, right-clicking the field and field calculating `null`.

Comment: @EmilBrundage is there specific criteria for what you select manually and what needs to be null? aka could it be automated?